# how to print an image using PHP: Printer

Tags: php, web-applications, printing

I have a printer directly attached to my PC and i am able to print texts using PHP.
what I want to know is, how can I print an image using the same php functions?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try having a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-draw-bmp.php and see if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation from:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php

But I don't see anything for printing image files in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the image to a bitmap file (.bmp).
You can then draw it using the function found here:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-draw-bmp.php

another option is to write d image into a pdf/postscript file and 
put into printer_write("filename.pdf").

You could also just copy the image to the spool folder.

Printing with PHP is really cool tho :D